# Parsing JSON responses and looking for specific variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, cheerio

I need to parse through and look for a specific id. In the code below I need to be able to pull out the id number. It looks like this `"itemIds":["918e337d-82ae-4e91-bdc3-16ad06572e21"`. I need to be able to pull the number "918e337d-82ae-4e91-bdc3-16ad06572e21". I have been having trouble understanding this concept. If you could send how or the actual code to do it . That would be very much appreciated.

```
{"dbSessionTokenMap":{"CXO_PC_ST":"e5b96399-fefc-4d9d-93ba-2aa1059008ce|{\"mtoken\":\"301:12#90271897#2=60818072#7=100439087\"}"},"id":"e5b96399-fefc-4d9d-93ba-2aa1059008ce","checkoutFlowType":"Guest","cartId":"ffd6cb2f-efc2-47b2-96d9-52d2cfb3d69b","items":[{"id":"918e337d-82ae-4e91-bdc3-16ad06572e21","offerId":"864A02B3BF7442A4802E6DF7BA2EDA28","productId":"1ZPTYHZN85S6","productName":"Pokemon Assorted Lot of 50 Single Cards [Any Series]","itemId":127446742,"sellerId":"A577588AB81D43AE9E7F468183B3568A","thumbnailUrl":"https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/aa6ed747-9cd0-44dc-b927-44bc2b7e1ca7_1.62c435484d4015af1c325e9cdeeb3662.jpeg?odnHeight=100&odnWidth=100&odnBg=FFFFFF","legacySellerId":3340,"productClassType":"REGULAR","quantity":1,"unitPrice":8.61,"type":"REGULAR","price":8.61,"unitOfMeasure":"EA","hasCarePlan":false,"brand":"Pok?mon","discount":{},"rhPath":"20000:25000:25003:25114:25333","isWarrantyEligible":false,"category":"0:4171:3318550:617941:8920388","primaryCategory":"Home Page/Toys/Shop Toys by Age/Toys for Kids 5 to 7 Years/Toys for Kids 5 to 7 Years","isCarePlan":false,"isEgiftCard":false,"isAssociateDiscountEligible":false,"isShippingPassEligible":false,"isTwoDayShippingEligible":false,"classId":"5","maxQuantityPerOrder":100,"isSubstitutable":false,"isInstaWatch":false,"isAlcoholic":false,"isSnapEligible":false,"isAgeRestricted":false,"isSubstitutionsAllowed":false,"fulfillmentSelection":{"fulfillmentOption":"S2H","shipMethod":"STANDARD","availableQuantity":172},"servicePlanType":"NONE","errors":[],"wfsEnabled":false,"isAlcohol":false}],"shipping":{"postalCode":"82001","city":"CHEYENNE","state":"WY"},"promotions":[{"promotionId":"1c2cbad1-205e-425f-9297-8629d68e97f6","okToPayAwards":[{"applyTo":"CART_FULFILLMENT_PRICE","actionType":"AWARD","name":"DS_Donors_Choose_Teachers_Card","awardType":"OK_TO_PAY","description":"DonorsChoose Card","applicableTo":{"ITEM_TAX":true,"SHIP_PRICE":true,"SHIP_TAX":true,"FEE":true,"ITEM_PRICE":true},"asset":{"image":"https://i5.walmartimages.com/dfw/63fd9f59-e0cf/455269aa-c4e8-46a5-8d76-5d4b458e1269/v1/Select_gift_card.png","imageAlt":""},"awardEligibleItemIds":[],"awardEligibleTotalsByItemId":{}}],"dsEligibleItemIds":[],"dsEligibleTotals":{}}],"summary":{"subTotal":8.61,"shippingIsEstimate":false,"taxIsEstimate":true,"grandTotal":8.61,"quantityTotal":1,"amountOwed":8.61,"merchandisingFeesTotal":0,"shippingCosts":[{"label":"Top Cut Central shipping","type":"marketplace_shipping","cost":0.0}],"shippingTotal":0.0,"hasSurcharge":false,"preTaxTotal":8.61,"addOnServicesTotal":0,"itemsSubTotal":8.61},"pickupPeople":[],"email":"","buyer":{"customerAccountId":"9afb345e-74b8-4afb-93d0-4bf52697e18f","isGuestSignupRequired":false,"isGuest":true,"isAssociate":false,"applyAssociateDiscount":false},"allowedPaymentTypes":[{"type":"CREDITCARD","cvvRequired":true},{"type":"PAYPAL","cvvRequired":false},{"type":"GIFTCARD","cvvRequired":false},{"type":"VISA_CHECKOUT","cvvRequired":false},{"type":"MASTERPASS","cvvRequired":false},{"type":"CHASEPAY","cvvRequired":false},{"type":"AMEX_CHECKOUT","cvvRequired":false}],"registries":[],"payments":[],"cardsToDisable":[],"allowedPaymentPreferences":[],"isRCFEligible":false,"isMarketPlaceItemsExist":true,"version":"v3","shippingCategory":{"shippingGroups":[{"itemIds":["918e337d-82ae-4e91-bdc3-16ad06572e21"],"seller":"Top Cut Central","defaultSelection":true,"fulfillmentOption":"S2H","shippingGroupOptions":[{"method":"EXPEDITED","methodDisplay":"Expedited","selected":false,"charge":8.99,"deliveryDate":1606766400000,"availableDate":1606766400000,"fulfillmentOption":"S2H","onlineStoreId":0,"isThresholdShipMethod":false},{"method":"STANDARD","methodDisplay":"Standard","selected":true,"charge":0.0,"deliveryDate":1606939200000,"availableDate":1606939200000,"fulfillmentOption":"S2H","onlineStoreId":0,"isThresholdShipMethod":false}],"isEdelivery":false,"hasWFSItem":false,"itemSellerGroups":[]}]},"entityErrors":[],"oneDaySelected":false,"paymentWithBagFee":false,"giftDetails":{"giftOrder":false,"hasGiftEligibleItem":false,"xoGiftingOptIn":false},"canApplyDetails":[],"dbName":"e5b96399-fefc-4d9d-93ba-2aa1059008ce|C","jwt":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiI1MjdmZTRjYi0wZjI5LTRjZWYtOWRiOS00Yzc1YWQ5MTMwNTQiLCJpYXQiOjE2MDYwOTY0NjMsImlzcyI6IjU3YjM0ZTNhZGE1MjkzMGEwYzBjYTFjOSIsIk9yZ1VuaXRJZCI6IjU2ZWJiMTJkZGE1MjkzMWRhOGZlMDc5YSIsIlJlZmVyZW5jZUlkIjoiZTViOTYzOTktZmVmYy00ZDlkLTkzYmEtMmFhMTA1OTAwOGNlIn0.-ta5UQLkJtXNR5yP2dOhDiDMF9dPpbfktAJu7z22kNM"}
```

Edit Below! Edit Below! Edit Below!

**For future visitors -**
I like to use split to find what I specifically need. For example for this problem I had above. I would just use

```
 let myId = string.split(`"itemIds":["`)[1].split('"')[0]
```

This should work well and I use this method all the time. If you have any better methods feel free to reply or leave an answer. You can also use JSON.parse(your data) and look for your specific variable that way. This article should also help you understand how to use it. https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/javascript-tutorial/javascript-json-parsing.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to determine which **prop** will you get the **value** of? And then try this, in this case I will get **"itemIds"** so my findProp function will take 2 parameters:

```js
const myObj = {
  dbSessionTokenMap: {
    CXO_PC_ST:
      'e5b96399-fefc-4d9d-93ba-2aa1059008ce|{"mtoken":"301:12#90271897#2=60818072#7=100439087"}',
  },
  id: "e5b96399-fefc-4d9d-93ba-2aa1059008ce",
  checkoutFlowType: "Guest",
  cartId: "ffd6cb2f-efc2-47b2-96d9-52d2cfb3d69b",
  items: [
    {
      id: "918e337d-82ae-4e91-bdc3-16ad06572e21",
      offerId: "864A02B3BF7442A4802E6DF7BA2EDA28",
      productId: "1ZPTYHZN85S6",
      productName: "Pokemon Assorted Lot of 50 Single Cards [Any Series]",
      itemId: 127446742,
      sellerId: "A577588AB81D43AE9E7F468183B3568A",
      thumbnailUrl:
        "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/aa6ed747-9cd0-44dc-b927-44bc2b7e1ca7_1.62c435484d4015af1c325e9cdeeb3662.jpeg?odnHeight=100&odnWidth=100&odnBg=FFFFFF",
      legacySellerId: 3340,
      productClassType: "REGULAR",
      quantity: 1,
      unitPrice: 8.61,
      type: "REGULAR",
      price: 8.61,
      unitOfMeasure: "EA",
      hasCarePlan: false,
      brand: "Pok?mon",
      discount: {},
      rhPath: "20000:25000:25003:25114:25333",
      isWarrantyEligible: false,
      category: "0:4171:3318550:617941:8920388",
      primaryCategory:
        "Home Page/Toys/Shop Toys by Age/Toys for Kids 5 to 7 Years/Toys for Kids 5 to 7 Years",
      isCarePlan: false,
      isEgiftCard: false,
      isAssociateDiscountEligible: false,
      isShippingPassEligible: false,
      isTwoDayShippingEligible: false,
      classId: "5",
      maxQuantityPerOrder: 100,
      isSubstitutable: false,
      isInstaWatch: false,
      isAlcoholic: false,
      isSnapEligible: false,
      isAgeRestricted: false,
      isSubstitutionsAllowed: false,
      fulfillmentSelection: {
        fulfillmentOption: "S2H",
        shipMethod: "STANDARD",
        availableQuantity: 172,
      },
      servicePlanType: "NONE",
      errors: [],
      wfsEnabled: false,
      isAlcohol: false,
    },
  ],
  shipping: { postalCode: "82001", city: "CHEYENNE", state: "WY" },
  promotions: [
    {
      promotionId: "1c2cbad1-205e-425f-9297-8629d68e97f6",
      okToPayAwards: [
        {
          applyTo: "CART_FULFILLMENT_PRICE",
          actionType: "AWARD",
          name: "DS_Donors_Choose_Teachers_Card",
          awardType: "OK_TO_PAY",
          description: "DonorsChoose Card",
          applicableTo: {
            ITEM_TAX: true,
            SHIP_PRICE: true,
            SHIP_TAX: true,
            FEE: true,
            ITEM_PRICE: true,
          },
          asset: {
            image:
              "https://i5.walmartimages.com/dfw/63fd9f59-e0cf/455269aa-c4e8-46a5-8d76-5d4b458e1269/v1/Select_gift_card.png",
            imageAlt: "",
          },
          awardEligibleItemIds: [],
          awardEligibleTotalsByItemId: {},
        },
      ],
      dsEligibleItemIds: [],
      dsEligibleTotals: {},
    },
  ],
  summary: {
    subTotal: 8.61,
    shippingIsEstimate: false,
    taxIsEstimate: true,
    grandTotal: 8.61,
    quantityTotal: 1,
    amountOwed: 8.61,
    merchandisingFeesTotal: 0,
    shippingCosts: [
      {
        label: "Top Cut Central shipping",
        type: "marketplace_shipping",
        cost: 0.0,
      },
    ],
    shippingTotal: 0.0,
    hasSurcharge: false,
    preTaxTotal: 8.61,
    addOnServicesTotal: 0,
    itemsSubTotal: 8.61,
  },
  pickupPeople: [],
  email: "",
  buyer: {
    customerAccountId: "9afb345e-74b8-4afb-93d0-4bf52697e18f",
    isGuestSignupRequired: false,
    isGuest: true,
    isAssociate: false,
    applyAssociateDiscount: false,
  },
  allowedPaymentTypes: [
    { type: "CREDITCARD", cvvRequired: true },
    { type: "PAYPAL", cvvRequired: false },
    { type: "GIFTCARD", cvvRequired: false },
    { type: "VISA_CHECKOUT", cvvRequired: false },
    { type: "MASTERPASS", cvvRequired: false },
    { type: "CHASEPAY", cvvRequired: false },
    { type: "AMEX_CHECKOUT", cvvRequired: false },
  ],
  registries: [],
  payments: [],
  cardsToDisable: [],
  allowedPaymentPreferences: [],
  isRCFEligible: false,
  isMarketPlaceItemsExist: true,
  version: "v3",
  shippingCategory: {
    shippingGroups: [
      {
        itemIds: ["918e337d-82ae-4e91-bdc3-16ad06572e21"],
        seller: "Top Cut Central",
        defaultSelection: true,
        fulfillmentOption: "S2H",
        shippingGroupOptions: [
          {
            method: "EXPEDITED",
            methodDisplay: "Expedited",
            selected: false,
            charge: 8.99,
            deliveryDate: 1606766400000,
            availableDate: 1606766400000,
            fulfillmentOption: "S2H",
            onlineStoreId: 0,
            isThresholdShipMethod: false,
          },
          {
            method: "STANDARD",
            methodDisplay: "Standard",
            selected: true,
            charge: 0.0,
            deliveryDate: 1606939200000,
            availableDate: 1606939200000,
            fulfillmentOption: "S2H",
            onlineStoreId: 0,
            isThresholdShipMethod: false,
          },
        ],
        isEdelivery: false,
        hasWFSItem: false,
        itemSellerGroups: [],
      },
    ],
  },
  entityErrors: [],
  oneDaySelected: false,
  paymentWithBagFee: false,
  giftDetails: {
    giftOrder: false,
    hasGiftEligibleItem: false,
    xoGiftingOptIn: false,
  },
  canApplyDetails: [],
  dbName: "e5b96399-fefc-4d9d-93ba-2aa1059008ce|C",
  jwt:
    "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiI1MjdmZTRjYi0wZjI5LTRjZWYtOWRiOS00Yzc1YWQ5MTMwNTQiLCJpYXQiOjE2MDYwOTY0NjMsImlzcyI6IjU3YjM0ZTNhZGE1MjkzMGEwYzBjYTFjOSIsIk9yZ1VuaXRJZCI6IjU2ZWJiMTJkZGE1MjkzMWRhOGZlMDc5YSIsIlJlZmVyZW5jZUlkIjoiZTViOTYzOTktZmVmYy00ZDlkLTkzYmEtMmFhMTA1OTAwOGNlIn0.-ta5UQLkJtXNR5yP2dOhDiDMF9dPpbfktAJu7z22kNM",
};

const findProp = (obj, prop, out) => {
  let i,
    proto = Object.prototype,
    ts = proto.toString,
    hasOwn = proto.hasOwnProperty.bind(obj);

  if ("[object Array]" !== ts.call(out)) {
    out = [];
  }

  for (i in obj) {
    if (hasOwn(i)) {
      if (i === prop) {
        out.push(obj[i]);
      } else if (
        "[object Array]" === ts.call(obj[i]) ||
        "[object Object]" === ts.call(obj[i])
      ) {
        findProp(obj[i], prop, out);
      }
    }
  }
  return out;
};

console.log(findProp(myObj, "itemIds"));
```

Comment: I found a simpler way to do it.

Comment: parse the json then just use selectors to get to what you need. For example

`const ExampleParse = JSON.parse(WhatYouNeedParsed.body);

 let ItemId1 = ExampleParse.firstselector.secondselector.ect`
my example is probably shitty but you get the idea. If you need more help just leave a comment.

Comment: @Prada I write the function that you can reuse for later, test because you do it your way, you just need to write a function and pass the key to it will work